# Bluetooth LE - deciding client vs. server

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

We are creating a piece of hardware (call it "the dongle") that responds to Bluetooth LE requests that come from a mobile phone, when the user requests it.  All communications will be initiated from the phone, the dongle will never initiate communications.  Communications, when they occur, will be very infrequent (maybe once a day) and will be short (a few hundred bytes).  When communications happens, we would like the dongle to respond within a few seconds without requiring the user to interact manually with the dongle (e.g. we don't want the user to have to press a button on the dongle to say "wake up and pay attention").

So thinking about power usage, it seems that when a device does a Bluetooth scan, the device doing the scanning is mostly just listening/receiving, and the device doing the advertising is doing the transmitting (right?).

But pages like [this one](http://projects.mbientlab.com/bluetooth-low-energy-basics/) say

```
Slave (or “peripheral“) devices advertise and wait for connections. Usually, the slave is a small device like a fitness tracker or a smartwatch.
```

Why would the small device (e.g. fitness tracker) be sitting there, broadcasting/advertising every few seconds forever (assuming it's not currently connected to anything)?  Doesn't that use up all kinds of power?  Wouldn't it make more sense for the small device to be in listening (scanning) mode instead?

And then once a connection is made, is there some kind of "keep alive" so the two connected devices "know" that the other one is still there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's take a chip specification sheet like [nRF51822](http://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/pdf/nRF51822_PS_v3.1.pdf) (see 8.5.2). You'll see power consumption is nearly the same for RX (13mA) and TX @ 0dBm (10.5mA). TX/RX power ratio will be the same [for](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/swrs084f/swrs084f.pdf) [other](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cc2650.pdf) [chips](http://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/pdf/nRF52832_PS_v1.1.pdf) [on](http://www.cypress.com/file/139841/download) [the](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-42426-SmartConnect-SAMB11-SOC_Datasheet.pdf) market: around 1x.

Now take into account transmission is a low duty-cycle operation (if you TX during 200us every 200ms, you are at 0.1%), average power consumption for advertising is low (10.5mA * 0.001 + 5uA * 0.999).
On the other hand, receiving is continuous by design: you never know when the packet will actually be transmitted, you need to be close to 100% duty cycle if you dont want to miss any packet (13mA, continuous).

So, for connection setup, Peripheral (that advertises) saves more power than Central (that listens) because it can sleep most of the time.

Once connected, both Central (Master) and Peripheral (Slave) track time with a "sleep clock" and wake up in a time-slotted manner to sync up and check for other party's presence. Slots are called "Connection Events" in the spec. Between connection events, they both sleep, so they both save power equally the whole time the connection lasts. (well, there is another optimization called "slave latency" that allows Peripheral (i.e. Slave) to save more power, but let's ignore it here...).

In your case, "the dongle" should advertise. The advertisement interval can be tuned to fit the acceptable reconnection time your application needs. 50-500 ms is typical for your kind of use.